# 'No such file or directory' when I install 'org-bullets'

Tags: org-mode

I'm trying to install the [`org-bullets`](https://github.com/sabof/org-bullets) mode and after pasting the install code given in the GitHub's site in `.emacs`, and paste the `.el` file into the home directory, I get this result.:

```
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading ‘c:/Users/nazao/AppData/Roaming/.emacs’:

File is missing: Cannot open load file, No such file or directory, org-bullets

To ensure normal operation, you should investigate and remove the
cause of the error in your initialization file.  Start Emacs with
the ‘--debug-init’ option to view a complete error backtrace.
```

Is this a problem with my `load-path?` What can I do?

I'm using Windows 10.

Comment: It seems that the problem is related just to your `load-path`.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you've saved the org-bullets.el file somewhere that isn't on your load-path. I don't know where the home directory is on Windows, but you'll need something like the following in your .emacs:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "c:/Users/nazao/AppData/Roaming/")
```

This assumes that org-bullets.el is in c:/Users/nazao/AppData/Roaming/. If it's somewhere else, modify accordingly.

org-bullets is also available in the [MELPA](https://melpa.org/#/) repository, so you could install it using the Emacs packing system instead of doing it by hand. See the "Getting Started" section of the linked page for details.